# heterogeneous input features for estimators in sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, ensemble-modeling

I would like to do ensemble on my model.
Two of them are SVM and XGBoosting. SVM could not tolerate null value and XGB can do it. So I have different features for each of them. but when VotingClassifier see null (even in condition that are not input for SVM) raise error!

is there any way to ensemble in this condition?

- it's not possible to impute null value